# Populate multiple Datagridviews with streaming data

Tags: c#, datagridview, async-await

I have being battling with this problem quite a few days.
It seems every single example i have seen relies on present data.
But in my case i have a stream that is processed and splitted into a number of string Arrays and with these i populate my DGVs.
The only (working) solution is this

```
public void AddRowsToDGVs()
{  
    for (int i = 0; i < dtblRepository.Length; i++)
    {
        if (dgvRepository[i].InvokeRequired)
        {
            dgvRepository[i].Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
            {
                foreach (String[] datao in dataToAdd.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    int indexOfDGV = Array.IndexOf(activeDatas, datao[0]);
                    dgvRepository[indexOfDGV].Rows.Insert(0, datao);
                    dgvRepository[indexOfDGV].Refresh();
                    Application.DoEvents();
                }
            }));
        }
        else
        Application.DoEvents();                   
    }
}
```

Some explaining :

- dtblRepository an Array of DataTables (for the time being it provides
  the index but later maybe i will dump it
- dgvRepository an Array holding the DGVs
- dataToAdd BlockingCollection populated from another routine
- activeDatas an Array holding the elements by which the stream will be
  processed
  And yes all the code depends on `Application.DoEvents()`
  The whole code runs by this:
  `trd = new Thread(AddRowsToDGVs);`
  `trd.Start()`

Eveyone seems to point to async/await but i just can't find a sample that fits my needs....can i get some help :)

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.aboutmycode.com/reactive-extensions/using-reactive-extensions-for-streaming-data-from-database/) on how to use [Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx) with streaming data. Might not be an actual answer at all but might change your point of view. Read up on SqlDependency, SignalR, ... as well. Lots of cool insights!

Comment: It seems interesting but like all the other examples it justs gets around the problem of having a responsive UI while loading data from existing data...